# What type of delimiter is being used?

Tags: c, file, parsing, delimiter

I'm attempting to parse a file without any sort of specification to guide me. I plan to split a section of this file into variable names, but I'm not sure how the fields are delimited. Clearly there is a pattern in the way the delimiters change...could someone point me in the right direction?

Here's the data I'm interested in (spaces added by me for clarity):

> @EEFDAAH  **TFLBFile** CM **ExecutionName** EL **FileContents** GI **%reserved** IJ  **&ReadCount** KE **vTest** B@CQETMV@Dmain@Ž¾àÅU

Full file (minus some invisible control characters):

```
MFP214DTest
JA
BMExecutionNameLFileContents
BCEAƒSTCF01TFLBFileTestRead0f36c096fa0~1~2~1~2~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~TFLBFile~TFLBFile~~0~0~2~0~0~0~0~1~0~0~0~0~0~0~ExecutionName~ExecutionName~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~1~0~0~0~0~FileContents~FileContents~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~1~0~0~0~0~0~1~~0~2~'Test'~15~0~1~0~FQ_dbopenwithfieldsDG_dbreadHprintoutFAHJ@A@WSHSJSGSASDSFSLQNhSHSJSGSISPQRhSESHQThSBTKf@EEFDAAHTFLBFileCMExecutionNameELFileContentsGI%reservedIJ&ReadCountKEvTestB@CQETMV@Dmain@Ž¾àÅU
```

Comment: Could you post the exact data please? No clarifying whitespace, just the exact data. Also, can you give us some context about where this file comes from? Also, try looking at the file in a hex editor.

Comment: Is it all text?  Are there newlines?

Comment: The invisible control characters are probably important.

Comment: @mckenzm There's an `EOT` immediately preceding the data I'm interested in, but no invisible characters after that one.

Answer (score 1):

It may have been better if you had posted one or two more records, and and hex as well. You firstly need to identify record types if they differ.  It does indeed look like the leading fields might be handled differently, a record level header, they look space delimited. Try assuming there is a fixed number of fields here. If this fails, there may be different record types and included data may be conditional upon a map or type at the beginning of the record. It may be possible the fields can be read in arbitrary sequence similarly to argv[] elements as value pairs. Architecture would also be useful information, trailing bytes look suspiciously binary..